# the else block in the following code isn't working and only the if statement is being executed to calculate the volume. What is going wrong?

Tags: python, pandas, if-statement, debugging

def volume(df):

```
for i in range(len(df['depth'])):
  if df['depth'][i] > 60 :
     df['volume']=df['x']*df['y']*df['z']
  else:
     df['volume'] = 8 
return df
```

> I am working to calculate volume of a diamond dataset where dimensions x,y,z and depth are given and I have to calculate volume = x*y*z when depth >60 else volume is to be set to 8 but the code I have written is not assigning volume =8 when depth <60 and simply calculates volume = x*y*z , perhaps the code isn't taking the else condtion initially is what i thought so I used a counter a which incremented by one when else block was executed and I printed its value successfully (my debug attempt) . Can you guys help me out in this ? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of looping, try this code:

```
import numpy as np
df['volume']=np.where(df['depth']>60, df['x']*df['y']*df['z'], 8)
```

Comment: thanks for the help, but what is the fault in the for loop?

Comment: If you want to iterate over rows you need to do it with df.iterrows(). When you are using df['volume']= it updates the whole column with the same value and not the specific row you are in.

Comment: Did my answer worked for you?